# Opencv : Get all "Point" stored in "Mat"

Tags: c++, opencv

I use **findNonZero(img, nonZeroCoordinates)** to store all the non-zero *points* in **nonZeroCoordinates**, which is a *Mat*.

Now I want to store all these *points* in a *vector* for further processing. My question is "**Is that possible to get all the points stored in mat in a simple way?**"

As far as I know, I can iterate through **nonZeroCoordinates** and store all the points one-by-one in the vector.

```
Mat nonZeroCoordinates;
vector<Point> inds;
for (int i = 0; i < nonZeroCoordinates.total(); i++) {
    Point pt(nonZeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i).x, nonZeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i).y);     
    inds.push_back(pt);
}
```

As you can see, the code looks quite redundant. Is it possible to make it simpler?

Comment: Save the temporary and do `inds.push_back(nonZeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV's findNonZero function excepts a vector of points as an output parameter as well.
Instead of storing the result in Mat object, you can store it directly in a vector, as follows:

```
vector<Point> inds;
cv::findNonZero(inputMatrix, inds);
```